# How to save a file to a directory

Tags: java, directory, text-files

What I have so far:

- A block of code that intakes a username and password and write it to a textfile.

  ```
  String usernameFilename;    
  usernameFilename = newUsernameField.getText();
  char[] signupPassword = newPasswordField.getPassword();
  String writePassword = new String(signupPassword);

  try {
      FileWriter userInfoWriter = new FileWriter(usernameFilename);
      BufferedWriter writeToFile = new BufferedWriter(userInfoWriter);   
      writeToFile.write(usernameFilename);  
      writeToFile.write("\r\n" + writePassword);
      writeToFile.close();
  ```

What I need to accomplish:

- Create a directory to a pre-made folder called `users`.
- Save the file to `usernameFilename` to a directory.

What I've tried:

- I've searched online everywhere! I cant find anything to do this :c

Extra info:
Since all computers are different, I would like to use the `.getAbsolutePath()` method when creating the directory.

Comment: Where does the `users` directory reside?  It's it in an absolute location or relative to the execution context of the app?

Comment: I'm new to this, so if this seems unconventional...now you know. I'm using netbeans ide. And when I open that project folder called "JavaNoteApp" which is the name of my project, it has all these folders like : build, dist, nbproject, src. The src file contains my java files but I created the "users" folder in the project folder "JavaNoteApp" along with the other folders.

Comment: Google is not your Java JDK docs. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

- [`java.io.File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)
- [`File#exists`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29)
- [`File#isDirectory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29)
- [`File#mkDirs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29)

You could update your code to look more look this...

```
String usernameFilename;    
usernameFilename = newUsernameField.getText();
char[] signupPassword = newPasswordField.getPassword();
String writePassword = new String(signupPassword);

File users = new File("users");
if ((users.exists() && users.isDirectory()) || users.mkdirs()) {

    FileWriter userInfoWriter = null;
    BufferedWriter writeToFile = null;
    try {
        userInfoWriter = new FileWriter(users.getPath() + File.seperator + usernameFilename);
        writeToFile = new BufferedWriter(userInfoWriter);   
        writeToFile.write(usernameFilename);  
                    writeToFile.newLine();
        writeToFile.write(writePassword);

        //....
    } finally {
        try {
            writeToFile.close();
        } catch (Exception exp) {
        }

    }

} else {
    throw new IOException("Could not create/find Users directory");
}
```